# How can one record a high frequency low volume sounds?

Tags: audio-recording, microphone-technique

Wish to capture high frequency sounds (up to 20kHz) at low volume estimated ~34-35 Db. The sound is non-directional and thus, source yet to be determined. First objective: capture the sound to document. Hardware is an M1 chip MacBook & UMIK-X mic. Willing to upgrade hardware.

Comment: 1) connect mic to computer. 2) launch recording software. 3) configure recording software to record mic to a track. 4) press record. I think you possibly might need to be a little clearer as to what question it is you need answered. I am sure it's not as simple as just this.

Comment: With frequencies up to 20 kHz, which is very close to the 22.05 kHz range limit with a typical 44.1 kHz sampling rate, I suggest you opt for 48 kHz at least. Seasoned hardware will support this (UMIK-X does), but I am not sure about the off-the shelf MacBook.

Also, if this is a technical/mechanical source, you might want to consider a different microphone.

Comment: Noise will be your enemy, when using analog devices. Try a digital recorder, like from the ZOOM series. For outdoor you'll certainly need whindshield protection and similar.